# Site guidelines

Tags: support, help-center

I am new to this site as well very naive in terms of Mathematical knowledge. I would like to know what are some things I am allowed to do, and what are some things I am not allowed to do here.  For example:- types of questions I can ask and types that I can't ask.

Also, can somebody tell me why I can comment on some questions but not on some other questions?

Comment: Have you tried consulting the help menus?

Comment: Hello 123, welcome to math SE :)

Comment: You are mostly supposed to figure these things out by yourself. Studying the Help Center is the local version of RTFM. For example, [privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Happy clicking and reading!

Comment: You can't comment everywhere until you have a minimum reputation of 50. Til then, you can comment only in your questions.

Comment: Kudos to you for posting this on the meta instead of the main site.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Where can I find it ?

Comment: On the top line of this page, over toward the right, where it says "help" (it may be somewhere else, if you're on a mobile).

Comment: @mrnovice Thank you.